Groovy: Accessing nested Map/Array/Map returning an array of one item array of the desired value instead of just the desired vaue
Couldn't find this issue anywhere else on the web.
Accessing an entry inside of a map inside of list inside of a map returns an one item array of the desired value rather than just the value.  For example
mainMap["info"] = []
mainMap["info"].add("metadata": "metadata1")
echo "mainMap["info"] " + mainMap["info"]
returns
[[metadata:metadata1]]
echo "mainMap["info"].metadata " + mainMap["info"].metadata
returns
[metadata1]
No matter what variation I try with either adding the single entry or accessing that single entry it always returns an array.
Thank you.
I've tried every variation that I know of to access map entries.
mainMap["info"].metadata
mainMap["info"].getAt("metadata")
mainMap.info.metadata
Blockquote

what's the result of mainMap.getClass(), mainMap.info.getClass() mainMap.info.metadata.getClass()? my guess it's not a plain map. you got it by parsing json with some specific version of json plugin.

Please update your question so we can reproduce what you're seeing

From a plain Groovy perspective, the easiest explanation would be, that
mainMap is not map, like the name suggests, but a list of maps.  And
your code utilizes the implicit spread operator.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What's tripping you up is Groovy GPath expressions. You have a list of maps, and you are accessing the elements of those maps to produce a list of values.
println 'mainMap["info"][0].metadata ' + mainMap["info"][0].metadata

These example helped me make sense of it.
